# Почему бросает ошибку AssertionError?

Tags: python

Всем привет! Решаю задачу для вуза, в которой нужно вывести словарь, состоящий из: 1) ключи - имена героев; 2) значения - количество символов в репликах этих героев.

Ответ правильный, но кидает ошибку AssertionError:

```
test_data = [
    ("", "{'#Bahram: 188', '#Zilziela: 415', '#Masha: 221'}")
]

for inp, out in test_data:
    with Tester([inp]) as t:
        c31()
        assert len(t) == 1, 'Incorrect answer'
        assert t[0] == out+'\n', 'Incorrect answer'
```

Мое решение:

```
def c31():
    with open('dialogs.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        arr = f.readlines()
        
        result_dict = {}
        
        for sentence in arr:
            if sentence.startswith('#'):
                author = sentence.split(':')[0] + ':'
                chars = len(sentence[len(author):-1].rstrip())
                if author in result_dict:
                    result_dict[author] += chars
                else:
                    result_dict[author] = chars
        return result_dict
```

Плюсом прикладываю текст из файлика "dialogs.txt"

```
#Бахрам: Считать умеешь? 
#Зильзиля: Умею. Раз, два, три, четыре, семнадцать, двадцать...так?
#Бахрам: Мда... А писать ты умеешь?
#Зильзиля: Писать не пробовал.
#Бахрам: И не пробуй!

#Бахрам: Считать и писать ты умеешь?
#Маша: Умею.
#Бахрам: Сколько будет пятью пять?
#Маша: Двадцать пять! 
#Зильзиля: Хозяин, это большой ученый, а!

#Бахрам: Я тебе мама, я тебе папа, и, конечно, дедушка.
#Зильзиля: Слушай, а я буду бабушка! Бабушка Зильзиля!

#Зильзиля: Там – чудесное творенье, сзади веревка, а на голове – вешалка!

#Маша: Скажи, Зильзиля, ты был в отпуске?
#Зильзиля: Что такое?
#Маша: Каждый человек один месяц в году должен отдыхать! Ты давно работаешь?
#Зильзиля: Тысячу лет!
#Маша: Ой, значит, тебе положено... 83 года отпуска.
#Зильзиля: Так! Все, ухожу в отпуск!
#Бахрам: Я тебе покажу «в отпуск»!

#Зильзиля: Я в темноте хорошо вижу...[бум]
#Маша: Ой, что это, Зильзиля?
#Зильзиля: Не пугайся Маша, это я, Зильзиля, головой стукнулся.
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вы не используете результат вызова функции c31() абсолютно никак. Что такое t и почему у него должен быть какой-то len, тоже непонятно

Comment: @andreymal Это уже вопрос к составителям данного теста. Мой код описан ниже

Comment: Если составители данного теста никак не используют возвращаемое вами значение, то ваша функция полностью бессмысленна, потому что возвращённый ею result_dict просто выбрасывается

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, тогда что мне делать в данном случае?

Comment: Ну видимо спросить у составителей данного теста, чего они от вас хотят вообще?

Comment: Можно начать с фразы «вывести словарь» — если возвращаемое значение никак не используется, то значит вывести не в return, ну так куда вывести-то тогда?

Comment: @andreymal, дописал тест, который был написан составителями. Можно ли что-то из исправленного понять?

Comment: Так как неизвестно, что такое Tester, — всё ещё нельзя, но мой хрустальный шар подсказывает мне, что под словом «вывести» может иметься в виду использование print